# Anyone can help me figure out why I got a wrong normal probability density figure with plot.hist function

Tags: python, plot, histogram

I have a numpy.array with the value between -0.15 to 0.15, plot probability density figure using plot.hist got the wrong figure, the y-axis value over 1.
the data I put as follow:

```
-3.159589616094560238e-02  
-2.238517986981702901e-02  
3.685513259832978727e-02  
5.551115123125782702e-17  
3.855829197377269590e-02  
1.106747485805819609e-01  
-1.343976685751569478e-01  
4.594910529316376113e-03  
4.908490856818659154e-04  
3.419692699076753994e-02  
-1.000969353410680052e-02  
-3.022899285774027778e-02  
-5.537409517542163373e-02  
-4.602923607484266100e-02  
3.284859133476397686e-02  
-1.023686626680164746e-02  
-3.664415656649880337e-02  
8.171815787883440763e-02  
2.999203027116759124e-02  
5.004522795043858663e-02  
7.388383006436807787e-02  
6.113278573286806683e-02  
6.386857025829173473e-02  
3.591723008598152189e-02  
6.549840356253561202e-02  
1.253856364955455160e-02  
6.041119437265624059e-02  
6.908608718235104140e-02  
1.134341604638248180e-01  
-1.576914025344122727e-02  
-2.417229901971842954e-02  
-3.899153022868465102e-02  
4.689096941761000670e-02  
5.841198683607556896e-02  
8.641413395100966399e-02  
5.642541143884205468e-02  
4.930903227540417433e-03  
1.942745077277890919e-02  
2.158310326121676281e-02  
1.049712334090066590e-02  
1.754053058915017171e-02  
-2.353744351610204122e-02  
-8.208313574505410326e-03  
5.744397964275682611e-02  
-1.211723809639734806e-01  
-8.992113883794172757e-02  
1.061556222415527273e-02  
-2.920395846191836675e-02  
1.037069716181004964e-03  
-3.161371576086063895e-02  
-3.612043404641407385e-02  
-1.809334659086286878e-02  
3.662870373600723983e-02  
1.391056336430290807e-02  
-1.172024701805174929e-01  
3.251886867868275521e-02  
2.396867235334465551e-02  
3.837332827102124533e-02  
6.056630689588365923e-02  
8.321671975043376523e-02  
1.115621200150082593e-01  
8.420054612809740879e-02  
5.823374107493473062e-02  
7.729794103241893755e-02  
2.477495629227444152e-02  
2.972088991663957014e-02  
3.742060783581174777e-02  
-1.110223024625156540e-16  
2.587337514429000063e-02  
1.527836714091357351e-02  
1.958896955617406288e-02  
-1.832210450473931163e-02  
-1.926657560263266011e-02  
2.339325805152586701e-02  
-6.324903516012525539e-02  
-6.690299051450193657e-02  
-2.482072685296415893e-02  
3.064499196744452370e-02  
3.355998562941886476e-02  
1.788746275401903452e-02  
4.613919286422546451e-03  
-8.927918985562194321e-03  
1.028462556431128383e-02  
5.532095657291985491e-02  
6.604320581321337924e-02  
3.669973111374175145e-02  
2.277477855616832914e-02  
4.808227903197481723e-02  
4.832747444828244809e-02  
7.656143177495855490e-03  
1.245515608493746873e-02  
2.349500690106676171e-02  
4.072972204376856808e-03  
2.516504860752621919e-02  
2.003738740895273651e-02  
-2.613223707890222069e-02  
4.011136596889314232e-03  
2.548231927644559192e-02  
1.330938824527588826e-02  
2.404439993147697296e-02  
6.907130907663830421e-03  
6.979484635157226502e-03  
-3.290848338052448918e-02  
-1.755191743006401239e-02  
-3.366674089662069491e-04  
5.945578987875954624e-05  
-1.632427050508156174e-02  
-8.658771138098070308e-02  
-4.820886804917889901e-02  
-8.546677486103770871e-03  
-6.925724668856880761e-03  
-9.925127350824403116e-04  
-2.449622387186950467e-02  
3.123051142945909575e-02  
5.795788098893345230e-02  
3.605543122998344785e-02  
3.302943330800275912e-02  
7.059531249141720588e-02  
5.853930993753908574e-02  
3.905874422983779404e-02  
4.843263815672965711e-02  
4.147627035435175191e-02  
8.400424535113787394e-02  
9.844201764532001242e-02  
9.294548499676424935e-02  
6.497483032833101246e-02  
1.144645348202695256e-01  
2.999608390738961461e-02  
3.085053739416804275e-02  
2.276726259836320265e-02  
0.000000000000000000e+00  
-2.510456168410146738e-02  
2.116637291906409146e-02  
-3.321700185738685196e-02  
3.982853772878908183e-03  
1.363191485535983349e-02  
1.564968650026804520e-02  
1.478997225428510531e-02  
-3.131685025064945282e-03  
-3.806954212751323396e-02  
-8.159214863622976655e-03  
-7.186257889362090978e-02  
-9.500427775385178464e-04  
-3.395150378118699797e-02  
7.110268582201983989e-03  
-2.162228010763439512e-02  
-5.384418762160989025e-02  
-7.415379224082696563e-03  
8.122245670091066128e-03  
-2.878373343427720332e-02  
-4.544898403509023410e-04  
2.231065952279343012e-02  
5.253618584763958266e-02  
7.567731789121345809e-03  
1.043630861213364069e-02  
9.691633727966997292e-03  
-2.829666135637745605e-03  
-1.504340107365054191e-03  
1.140727886561562765e-02  
1.089115013359434614e-02  
1.044992233561446715e-02  
9.693261114407991652e-03  
-5.238694978638769317e-02  
-2.457125444725005714e-02  
1.077886426445628931e-03  
-4.871118148953068605e-02  
-6.495809610443054050e-02  
-3.267035029465242824e-02  
-2.674999216286094716e-02  
-3.357327749680671936e-02  
-8.093857036171048236e-03  
4.214960036162579415e-02  
8.643719482737677318e-03  
-5.065308732882500831e-02  
-1.275187831141166850e-02  
4.968104321639105203e-03  
3.038550497837352871e-02  
1.292634450475451113e-01  
9.960248360301909853e-02  
9.926289065772253561e-02  
1.218752249462111137e-01  
6.588591178993197239e-02  
5.093094629578931443e-02  
4.116752669646578378e-02  
4.345115715519703992e-02  
1.576461619520656832e-02  
4.396757184635238791e-03  
-4.521077126215883313e-03  
1.461648603205449592e-02  
4.788312032257657780e-02  
2.755872630307917848e-02  
6.861615560310868611e-03  
2.549852881708733476e-02  
-5.168013319340802880e-03  
-1.887369212351849845e-02  
-2.441207169456885429e-02  
-3.320040226240705827e-02  
-6.425229768996637558e-02  
-3.663909065452941594e-02  
-3.102327088584733161e-02  
-4.127076305809684875e-02  
-5.684992379213882341e-03  
2.906307859990353570e-03  
-3.900653434877507375e-02  
1.512074322144520977e-01  
-2.515933869270309264e-02  
-6.296389906200300368e-02  
-9.272701261054544508e-02  
-4.790753677805792421e-03  
4.813151476583615862e-02  
7.650062035746391098e-02  
3.302890273769037988e-04  
5.380904266441388639e-03  
-2.202552482575392823e-03  
-2.787433399598707173e-04  
3.384160594702279035e-02  
1.300796256094960412e-02  
-1.160214859858521574e-02  
-6.277244073332632901e-02  
-1.903552999494984022e-02  
1.025375794049160350e-02  
-1.097075016073090215e-03  
-5.379827426551375691e-02  
-2.094588005309211409e-02  
-2.364953944195369306e-02  
-2.383070948888221796e-02  
-1.750399960104281893e-02  
1.497421083089922611e-02  
2.725070332141532603e-02  
7.403530041943423567e-02  
3.001483011466621331e-02  
4.337594882232209681e-02  
6.706027060741315271e-02  
7.233079294473854226e-02  
1.292045961433705981e-01  
1.877234340958466863e-02  
6.212823063689587588e-02  
8.667098195715983167e-02  
7.350219246286576746e-02  
3.159743487146293717e-02  
5.139887107014962098e-02  
1.935309979350974263e-02  
-3.410445703281306251e-04  
9.794976840847402499e-03  
-6.959086538445014014e-03  
1.201927489478310518e-02  
1.439413096064678932e-02  
-4.486192051086429489e-02  
-1.529194554502161241e-02  
-3.072446651081427171e-02  
-3.430002826759373513e-02  
1.718162677056368770e-02  
3.225957229830100914e-03  
-1.497698355531706937e-02  
-1.331288468251978774e-02  
1.659058944413624448e-02  
2.663588063070934653e-02  
-5.922524084111119302e-03  
5.636060111551793872e-03  
-2.049342974060008871e-02  
-3.803998428758581518e-02  
1.830300118925570763e-03  
3.424729726582459444e-02  
-2.895366428311385576e-02  
-3.386403989355701860e-02  
-7.079295637878763037e-02  
-7.093079263306317772e-02  
3.198451446435424117e-02  
9.545864656146652028e-02  
-7.516704766287746198e-02  
-8.108517870498599400e-02  
-1.177430403484454047e-01  
-3.120935658466644780e-02  
9.223154995107774035e-02  
-1.941212424528665492e-02  
3.411902669265831634e-03  
-2.354139203324806529e-03  
-3.071645493442498598e-02  
-4.164925521383888718e-02  
-3.122691837708191365e-02  
2.883660684356703641e-02  
-5.717969520583865428e-02  
-6.697810496817224735e-03  
9.441536785215753902e-03  
4.728317922800373552e-03  
2.049464471048090264e-03  
5.739566329777823217e-02  
7.567444227145320168e-02  
5.682425425263715191e-02  
2.127495371418597347e-02  
5.243610080135335805e-02  
6.029907063806672074e-02  
6.969759432272237820e-02  
5.641399207835956497e-02  
7.288261681999158581e-02  
5.756469121404828027e-02  
7.178193358914231048e-02  
5.381813355449260872e-02  
9.644985199153865985e-02  
6.435194910225061626e-02  
1.117112490506719791e-01  
2.439163554038270565e-02  
2.557084230623229981e-03  
2.469910898473459682e-02  
-9.569424158990702534e-03  
-5.173909847879420987e-02  
-2.771943460190381958e-02  
-7.918742305681764071e-03  
-3.247312870800173057e-02  
-3.910586948488503634e-03  
-3.242901716659532529e-02  
6.020118668182583566e-03  
1.858335310757686099e-02  
1.685456044577338108e-02  
-3.478529517587825026e-02  
-5.549822951020677575e-02  
1.016235026400252872e-02  
2.200445534907724543e-02  
3.048728364537484081e-02  
3.272163712735043362e-02  
2.395435266492118576e-02  
2.480370438536083633e-02  
1.056266120762306415e-01  
-1.082460774310889384e-01  
-1.347452419485566932e-01  
-7.714839854654403917e-02  
-1.900100074423183294e-02  
-2.368723808155448474e-03  
0.000000000000000000e+00  
-2.355757032900079873e-02  
9.196526397255683216e-03  
-1.249529199393473178e-03  
-3.236878688899802459e-02  
-3.136013706852952554e-02  
-5.156107379348240372e-04  
-1.377622880706341757e-01  
-2.396047220463182192e-02  
-9.684884856711595269e-02  
-1.842852002418049473e-02  
-3.176145780247169315e-02  
-4.241533961730808988e-02  
-2.973026167434550393e-02  
-1.646074567045308079e-02  
6.668870098842760719e-03  
5.033457963755305631e-02  
2.969935511689753005e-02  
5.231368543525652393e-02  
5.162632846998616021e-02  
7.889039094445621236e-02  
8.296260101450758651e-02  
9.697524611355656798e-02  
8.633834112993971077e-02  
1.005506084517912013e-01  
1.164298262869764011e-01  
1.025027965383787376e-01  
1.135352705294886966e-01  
1.008843418671770964e-01  
1.088638311190759378e-01  
2.884552324651995514e-02  
3.991830833263365630e-02  
4.760570909695638342e-02  
1.693027396115567851e-02  
3.933182809711910366e-02  
-6.408816681512249924e-02  
-5.529609835923893213e-02  
-2.993717135309542643e-02  
-8.085331618384095087e-03  
-6.185204488784304400e-02  
-1.196921502674397897e-01  
-4.780768033549070983e-02  
-1.274389715508722487e-02  
-1.280925978066266291e-02  
-4.849996655662441869e-02  
-3.646866106294993637e-02  
-2.756873004038262742e-02  
-5.356826427281805025e-02  
-6.242776544651362780e-02  
-6.124211990236372305e-02  
-5.686055405028850318e-02  
-2.817431694836830536e-02  
1.500375567808898136e-02  
-6.187659459197802914e-02  
-5.409826477572732273e-02  
2.261388915804851685e-02  
6.426257712815597323e-02  
1.157463639073508244e-02  
5.004890564395303443e-02  
-3.950616854542954304e-03  
-6.239557142348028940e-02  
-8.200269713949936978e-03  
-1.251492744667737078e-03  
-1.265801790937595150e-01  
-1.768421559080157746e-02  
2.027397358647520242e-02  
4.478253635871065619e-03  
1.878158237154076149e-02  
6.594154561536602621e-02  
7.452069498742991405e-02  
7.496480550402284670e-02  
9.538428783854202564e-02  
1.038856363174851527e-01  
1.424821557236105596e-01  
1.308412610257474462e-01  
1.168959152275381719e-01  
7.850467133577615497e-02  
7.777115662308897726e-02  
5.981982514235850701e-02  
8.319277680590930757e-02  
5.805864235677821172e-02  
3.503989261654183451e-02  
6.941485649918266443e-02  
3.136830512895127931e-02  
2.623864649120127845e-02  
-1.226727174267633336e-02  
1.110223024625156540e-16  
-7.376709615168980383e-03  
-9.038478471914745960e-03  
6.986774001545778545e-03  
-3.856365183713572620e-03  
-8.619184960484249647e-03  
-3.262580246123072958e-02  
-4.651261401455147881e-02  
-3.236697476015598651e-02  
-1.641180100241046436e-02  
-6.535594391774748879e-02  
-1.126080952657532719e-01  
-1.189511381184812644e-01  
-5.890481919610351946e-02  
-5.552142369774434871e-02  
-6.347500718128468167e-02  
-7.750984210293726528e-02  
-4.330385478438258939e-02  
-7.595236886221326533e-02  
-1.040841842177327170e-01  
-7.866565189792984469e-02  
-9.107533039278314924e-02  
-9.729503258398433663e-02  
-5.155961606225628602e-02  
5.716840813781481900e-02  
-1.467829770886464047e-02  
3.556038290053020745e-03  
2.142707048989228591e-02  
-3.531625991868403425e-03  
4.356573820064091329e-02  
-5.679040673184049259e-02  
-1.487776052507348845e-02  
-8.124221123796410149e-02  
-5.060338391158325511e-03  
-8.053437474883629044e-03  
-1.801016783423853296e-02  
-1.279701804251587305e-02  
-1.642983927022667601e-02  
-1.281404297380123181e-02  
-3.444779062880543030e-03  
1.814529853593149777e-02  
3.516420765789823877e-02  
2.194975082694949897e-02  
2.529998463330923597e-02  
4.464264850721472166e-02  
7.643078317437868030e-02  
7.041322144265371730e-02  
8.296155058167570262e-02  
6.615983653818824362e-02  
4.794770816378934875e-02  
8.856734114244479983e-02  
1.258800873696094280e-01  
1.389593385184824115e-01  
1.498281355904477197e-01  
1.224574555233136630e-01  
5.483186431966596830e-02  
5.535402888271356847e-02  
5.142137446889100127e-02  
7.029411589955203432e-02  
5.593633317006369010e-02  
4.714150671382522084e-02  
1.297478763856257933e-02  
4.059793489800239685e-02  
-3.198355232442939844e-03  
-1.578471874227083127e-02  
4.172631884570843219e-04  
-5.481128123112230521e-03  
3.958899824310690985e-03  
4.854634907375310338e-02  
4.584641828536167862e-02  
1.283691456912186557e-02  
2.086772456778712703e-04  
-3.883286527456911164e-03  
-6.978568771350529554e-03  
-8.249607438330544551e-03  
-1.821024504781104669e-02  
-6.823049190367941330e-02  
-2.846369680876015273e-02  
-4.060232727333634717e-03  
-9.065014927890668872e-02  
-8.837841688435754683e-02  
-1.078654283198097197e-01  
-3.953937130379669984e-02  
-2.733287728915720360e-02  
-8.152640242757383526e-02  
-1.308357512176841209e-01  
-8.044444184031515621e-02  
-6.068031562392728340e-02  
1.875986720832878429e-02  
-5.897929249547850805e-02  
7.073991497246079341e-03  
-6.090570638678616255e-02  
-5.462943813919063363e-02  
-3.270271938640623155e-02  
-3.791898647128666422e-02  
1.684196769300894125e-02  
5.299040124461584789e-02  
1.727334198115798580e-02  
-3.262538445267304521e-02  
-6.460900206302327975e-03  
-4.187876007718888127e-03  
2.104051828145839242e-03  
-6.456440906927712886e-02  
-8.241220464780019128e-02  
-1.584243463877277325e-02  
-4.451124106025378113e-02  
6.204589027608536922e-02  
-5.111202513504803369e-02  
-3.414571659963860917e-02  
-5.465147093469502337e-02  
-4.490135130341305070e-02  
3.297457022298994067e-02  
1.138019688518973616e-01  
4.166481086785100985e-02  
2.925682593430106726e-02  
8.335791832102096288e-02  
1.134549440008136845e-01  
5.318986808574899250e-02  
6.326665121558505689e-02  
2.901205218965235977e-02  
2.709286653167519709e-02  
6.061274790290466230e-02  
1.854683369224696676e-02  
2.902103450321780187e-02  
-1.466493757378331542e-02  
-8.450799006366985222e-03  
3.238752353295620834e-02  
6.883611128938593726e-03  
6.304336365859447566e-03  
2.662321664874278682e-02  
2.746320655555406498e-02  
3.603443934644601221e-02  
2.116640782743439697e-02  
5.846297720502810491e-03  
6.489046663897499179e-02  
-2.212720929445577411e-03  
-2.189626238306757733e-02  
1.809448480885464394e-02  
-4.258279898892736171e-02  
1.815539971975982381e-02  
-6.637756744883388516e-02  
-1.195477794535662885e-01  
-7.761629593318347675e-02  
-6.528221527559652237e-02  
-7.510948509456635835e-02  
-3.241960469112911691e-02  
-5.811779465876976136e-02  
-7.162919591932115360e-02  
-1.017479140369489388e-01  
-6.804471305478898557e-02  
-3.655182112120397564e-02  
-3.468655899873923643e-02  
-7.787662238841774887e-02  
-6.998641259933852110e-02  
-4.354185850015890313e-02  
-5.011636796222052048e-02  
-3.801528925170127859e-02  
1.260090902987887063e-02  
4.423447876462893724e-02  
1.283787124659774292e-02  
4.949812209368315008e-02  
-7.727269529949953863e-03  
9.282469058985345911e-03  
-1.151166856591892551e-02  
-5.171058003512418733e-03  
-1.198847871951366773e-02  
-1.294468509956125946e-03  
2.798713296447363774e-02  
3.586060178983307978e-02  
-7.076132206619289988e-04  
-9.774184452153625302e-02  
-1.060006385825577602e-01  
-6.756566877045661057e-02  
-1.298748714533518867e-01  
-1.005912904186360146e-01  
-9.437547579407315479e-02  
-5.801209316061123333e-02  
-4.550554546462615146e-02  
-2.970686610155373608e-02  
2.036190620496108883e-02  
-6.334074918455723235e-03  
1.300144335549104913e-01  
8.996752652747164181e-02  
-3.443754124748399370e-03  
2.744909628221592346e-02  
8.856880872205730171e-02  
3.401716662605136499e-02  
9.291635086396965448e-03  
2.668220571054702450e-02  
3.144660703649948541e-02  
4.554336909825346114e-02  
7.471406035640879018e-03  
4.177724765576401600e-03  
2.949815659979121429e-03  
7.726256994904215358e-03  
-1.183780950302602830e-02  
-8.331527641184180433e-03  
-6.449427336969112967e-03  
-2.357439184548476563e-03  
1.572601140811527576e-02  
5.618800754135233610e-03  
-4.734364951055336501e-03  
-4.310085917632522357e-02  
-1.000801848423465978e-02  
-7.031537055423214833e-02  
-9.082154353565163873e-02  
-7.165060423128888356e-02  
-4.435286882606784276e-02  
-5.449526586614975021e-02  
-5.823660056605653446e-02  
-1.177647112629865989e-01  
-1.460010232247108408e-01  
-9.955322836098917660e-02  
-1.104748314340267545e-01  
-7.259346385162268600e-02  
-1.106944801930266620e-02  
-3.681924821616411325e-02  
-9.659448510554280443e-03  
-1.843394276381193908e-02  
3.517119076792252219e-03  
3.530318740158017166e-02  
-2.448237276752554537e-02  
-8.324086961505566817e-02  
-5.846226565018575183e-02  
-4.413306998637939182e-02  
-3.028123726983295017e-02  
-1.749517293355967729e-02  
-4.239388057717285996e-02  
-7.463936401822154898e-02  
-7.610312681716457917e-02  
-3.400887292327570144e-02  
1.279300671485920637e-01  
-8.000494443979655479e-03  
6.057720685599143895e-02  
2.338262587606632081e-02  
3.357008922451221178e-02  
4.446097061532966466e-02  
4.985567466467188957e-02  
-3.729651991065656425e-02  
-1.123452980897715614e-02  
-1.290967152574694354e-02  
-1.169785420119778818e-03  
4.339304671458821261e-03  
7.960208457236550572e-03  
1.612425145210272248e-02  
-1.357566069003079967e-02  
-1.897636113688777604e-02  
-2.127467682317307762e-02  
5.688677706903066955e-02  
1.167397147122162249e-03  
-5.238090444095563902e-02  
-8.033229756483753481e-02  
-5.638668031346266707e-02  
-8.770126909852105079e-02  
-1.139703122313763251e-01  
-1.091441073080444135e-01  
-9.308666913218882621e-02  
-1.318168247245212754e-01  
2.785215405331337157e-02  
-1.706111939405730027e-03  
-1.044319809233721918e-01  
-1.517829994094719304e-01  
-1.054769050331120228e-01  
1.423877469064789847e-01  
1.153685494681763735e-02  
-8.706359502361496472e-03  
1.135425261481345927e-03  
1.441192789427614418e-03  
-1.482166852378000166e-02  
-2.741693694998395547e-02  
3.842834910067111087e-02  
-3.016686231083920422e-03  
-6.272337600095162502e-02  
-2.945125575841017751e-02  
-8.265012146342437527e-02  
-6.854100855556741201e-02  
-5.195084362038110415e-02  
-7.411749468435571697e-02  
-2.486286453376224115e-02  
-6.187847656496281434e-02  
-2.968894745884106956e-02  
1.762643206525443818e-02  
1.294560182734616482e-02  
4.221917108300238253e-02  
9.920310650409752684e-02  
8.521827899351425151e-02  
9.774522370312288544e-03  
7.499195679634462763e-02  
2.732722326513375988e-02  
6.350451310634608326e-02  
6.490460864797181761e-02  
5.707981988600985268e-02  
1.844500040724739165e-02  
1.417147248904337964e-02  
7.990194193126673450e-03  
1.009520255724344340e-02  
3.898843403253271500e-02  
-1.155609759566522676e-02  
-2.519440484900131727e-03  
2.253313653278327111e-03  
5.827885242445790537e-03  
9.190962784846823386e-03  
1.160732911085857189e-03  
-5.275909555766289394e-03  
3.381787516318887632e-02  
-2.721033970278663450e-02  
-5.244285970630779836e-02  
4.875759422490227868e-02  
4.600835429833582957e-03  
-3.087228383610574056e-02  
8.917388299658379758e-03  
-3.113625653331408838e-02  
-1.478572370454844798e-02  
4.940881828154741751e-02  
-2.336867791265717642e-02  
-5.379793719052139434e-02  
-4.291909741123584032e-02  
-7.477199403031892233e-02  
-7.442517841205104068e-02  
-1.248234745779867039e-01  
-1.379519428221240851e-01  
-1.371746383883072351e-01  
-1.410640080491438464e-01  
-7.153402382767853895e-02  
-7.951004471596795353e-02  
-1.459334568545657129e-01  
-6.895284700299986191e-03  
2.746149785201490445e-03  
2.308385727351258687e-03  
-7.994019877111374628e-02  
-5.890325063153001306e-02  
-8.784983164698587088e-02  
-6.129444879220657949e-02  
-6.467969716770757826e-02  
-5.258220008153868807e-02  
-3.986417666108588165e-02  
-6.480401394489507250e-02  
-7.151191855893396232e-02  
1.055472282177393750e-01  
5.440200566045894082e-02  
3.656338981196360916e-02  
6.555135724368527095e-02  
8.778637220420631992e-02  
7.209217548046492618e-02  
4.669587885186798903e-02  
5.361773176019690723e-02  
2.100601311910893498e-02  
6.322721469066044930e-02  
6.324133263799930349e-02  
2.644507624189262884e-02  
6.493048045675509083e-02  
4.137328830399938928e-02  
-1.590679399124483862e-02  
1.906620985511198185e-03  
1.176733236402961735e-02  
-2.724327187162875474e-02  
-1.694316454009803241e-03  
7.151084022793061101e-03  
-2.518011196291669584e-02  
-6.830186397384752084e-03  
3.839225472878626810e-04  
-6.383522099629515556e-03  
3.213803800869874383e-02  
6.646280411769012186e-03  
3.469305590503041214e-03  
3.161514171528406747e-03  
3.286238069597990918e-03  
1.312624149812902097e-02  
1.332620754499003191e-02  
2.640736755382855350e-02  
3.996890614732073743e-02  
-2.128863487235810315e-02  
-7.933393845336322858e-02  
-3.302483636109176945e-02  
-1.015654416187094511e-01  
-1.325651062865587093e-01  
-1.160991618245051926e-01  
-1.064432056694104567e-01  
-1.184449020589762869e-01  
-6.400724828316428638e-02  
-1.016812531739407222e-01  
-7.798906219928736228e-02  
-8.767094074204545562e-02  
-8.131929970818713160e-03  
-4.266889541076873682e-03  
-8.051025079016255193e-02  
-8.142489159399107779e-02  
-6.463343952452976771e-02  
-3.477208304841689079e-02  
-6.169485922106210385e-02  
-7.794801571513843008e-02  
-5.875547413448400924e-02  
-2.948747628264225540e-02  
-2.468786350077079028e-02  
6.316931852297980043e-03  
1.675770593459768865e-02  
8.440158329731495268e-03  
3.407307521354102642e-02  
4.046558954161111332e-02  
5.333240427857222077e-02  
9.984317230508371610e-02  
6.380628672903065901e-02  
6.821895425172957994e-02  
7.726852029029263047e-02  
1.099879223841040976e-01  
1.154725109215001821e-01  
1.289915848947860155e-01  
1.168403187068005611e-01  
7.601204755920465406e-02  
5.760226131262197180e-02  
6.111537335727673659e-02  
4.615846941988716035e-02  
5.338692740816225468e-02  
5.555730080338849852e-02  
9.043577779408418227e-02  
7.540903584304714524e-02  
7.434934358590894465e-02  
-4.715512399759397288e-02  
7.006223732701544193e-03  
3.364841554370112675e-03  
1.690409671780922218e-02  
1.103833164924136745e-02  
1.126494343287030159e-02  
4.057932819030787841e-03  
1.368619273598631336e-03  
4.626015404370703576e-02  
2.132559203921788327e-03  
-1.265471233206300061e-02  
-4.516990638789936119e-03  
-7.155526544551302215e-03  
-1.352277613288392633e-02  
2.621463144352664809e-02  
1.939461416689092221e-02  
6.185211299288173592e-03  
8.045623312930225146e-03  
4.407589536537970254e-03  
1.191666034032462518e-02  
6.547637500250988452e-03  
6.270007122786691589e-03  
2.630044414796584018e-03  
5.806308029044277008e-03  
8.511179399315754734e-04  
-2.362464244201878394e-02  
-3.380972184650721246e-03  
6.357541814028117022e-03  
1.537197145284752153e-02  
6.342725900758727775e-02  
7.259079807480606217e-02  
1.157786344750846297e-01  
7.184128864328309660e-02  
-1.035335901320000307e-02  
4.168878403254561160e-02  
6.321671510862214571e-02  
6.721673864842980795e-02  
-8.634059593854637171e-02  
-6.710734873617735241e-02  
-5.401885723027677333e-02  
-9.033267165973468682e-02  
6.077874509055947172e-03  
-3.288646725657162762e-02  
-6.980608224949735874e-02  
-9.304199209365759948e-02  
4.102947654724820037e-02  
1.304906824207752170e-02  
3.284161330384344213e-02  
-1.083123574638507891e-01  
-3.474140936233205412e-02  
-3.115680830226313924e-02  
-8.954540738243413345e-02  
-4.195714073667794475e-02  
-8.509552666629494055e-02  
-9.544602778678318300e-02  
-7.612007930937042532e-02  
-5.777839588658773007e-02  
-5.979117785777282590e-02  
-9.303876566862379072e-04  
-1.835442822550326092e-03  
5.093692506767105721e-02  
7.321897028698953758e-03  
2.843994192835286317e-02  
3.652328472779242663e-02  
5.976919248128853557e-02  
5.578086382840818924e-02  
-4.312149138461496278e-02  
7.607358466719998935e-02  
5.186506528253109760e-02  
1.066872150488835103e-01  
2.317293301517714399e-02  
8.358124769813657373e-02  
1.212137536909758118e-01  
1.088231327200454568e-01  
2.702684551830986104e-02  
2.980740712067009301e-02  
7.117852449560413408e-02  
5.029681501193783433e-02  
6.926432731488418870e-02  
3.138751560408248320e-02  
5.240655701285723556e-02  
5.934528699975138988e-02  
7.562571076104612766e-02  
5.959577823875922276e-02  
4.831664684117192854e-03  
1.507431192400966735e-02  
1.757792668096593014e-03  
-5.219913345067189736e-03  
-7.026869437085692116e-03  
-4.846569770470751659e-03  
-5.317193298629660503e-03  
-6.900490373682011125e-03  
-4.672818975354944837e-03  
-5.622143765235121382e-04  
1.316040200243101532e-02  
-4.197649878046133542e-03  
2.545967639584312270e-03  
3.191690482571410414e-03  
1.116690262505298792e-03  
7.411148270822009998e-03  
9.477059769268714184e-03  
7.852044959877985120e-03  
-1.756565812885621525e-03  
-4.869098454477943649e-03  
-2.685139186935664446e-03  
-1.085590845068482024e-02  
1.059285359914305391e-02  
1.849516730946226817e-02  
4.222865377134421561e-02  
-8.785324111355796717e-03  
1.874835920114170662e-03  
9.396433027552286710e-02  
5.248701611436867864e-02  
6.487698256645951789e-02  
9.643773387012782861e-02  
7.471527239577763213e-02  
9.961300302901632264e-02  
8.589476044726551685e-02  
3.321503310077345006e-02  
-1.211545818919109729e-01  
5.532271038215685888e-02  
-1.409394383388486438e-01  
-8.514245610785636798e-02  
-4.886889620580692206e-02  
-4.712974967948441174e-02  
-2.021370739854932985e-02  
-2.971153093296480252e-02  
-1.479922118615240034e-02  
-1.271505988488993433e-01
```

I have tried using `panda.DataFrame` plot or `seaborn.distplot` all have the same wrong figure. so I think the problem may come from the data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sn


data = np.loadtxt('data.txt')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#ax.hist(data, bins=20, density=1)
sn.distplot(data, bins=20)
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

in the probability density figure, the y-axis value should be below 1.0, I want to figure out what happened in my data.

Answer (score 0):

Continous pdf never says the value has to be less than 1, with the pdf for the continuous random variable, function p(x) is not the probability. You can refer to continuous random variables and their distributions.

Comment: I just got a set of scatter, it is not continuous random variables, they are just random soil moisture difference values.